# Can not check radio/Checkbox in head of accordian-jquery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Folks,
How can i check/uncheck radio or checkbox in Accordian panel header?

See the this code snippet:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>
   <a href="#">
     <input type="checkbox" value="222" class="treeChkBox" />
     Some Value
   </a>
  </h3>
  <div>
</div>
```

Is jquery suppressing click event on this?

Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/teBfb/

Comment: Please add working code to http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

yes you can check/uncheck using jquery

> $('#treeChkBox').live("click",function(event){
>                   $('#treeChkBox').attr("checked",false);
>               })

```
        <h3>
            <a href="#">
                <input type="checkbox" value="222" id="treeChkBox" class="treeChkBox" />Some Value</a></h3>


        <div>
        </div>
```

same way you can make it checked as attr("checked","checked")